# How does Windows know my Network usage percentage in Task Manager?

Tags: windows, networking

Isn't that maximum ultimately set by my ISP if I'm within hardware spec? How does Windows know within my hardware capability how much I'm allotted/paying for?

Comment: well, Windows can determine your average max bandwidth if it wanted to just by examining its network analytic information , but in reality, I believe that it is measuring based on the capacity of your network card, not the Internet throughput. if you have a 100Mb/s NIC, and your process traffic is 10Mb/s, then the process is responsible for using 10% of the network capability. That said though, windows probably won't notice that the process is using 67% of your 15Mb/s ISP service.

Comment: Windows uses its data collection system to know about your network, disk, and CPU usage. It is just for that computer and not the network. It does not track your ISP

Comment: There are some modems (ADSL and 3G/4G USB modems, I believe) that may be able to report uplink speed. However, it also sounds possible you may be mistaking Windows detecting your maximum network card capacity for your ISP connection capacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those figures are the percentage of your current connection's maximum theoretical throughput & has absolutely no correlation to your total network data allowance, or line speed. It is measuring the fastest you can connect to your router - wifi or ethernet, so could be measuring a percentage of 1 Gbps. If your line is only 100 Mbps, you'll never see anything over 10% because your line can only do 10% of the speed of your ethernet connection.

If you watch it for a while, you'll notice it will decrease when there is less activity. If it was measuring your data allowance, it would never decrease… it would also have to know when your data allowance refreshes for next month, which is highly unlikely too ;)